# Cell's text overflow neighbor cell with explicit empty declaration

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

So, I have this situation like shown in the image (link below) where cell B1 has a long text that doesn't fit his width, and cell C1 has an IF evaluation that if True, should display a text in the cell, otherwise should be empty, and since I can't just leave the ELSE part empty, I have to put an empty string, but the text in B1 doesn't overflow over it. I want the text to overflow to the following empty columns, wrapping isn't what I want.
Is there any way that I can overcome this? Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of the situation to better illustrate]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this if you offset your formula like:

```
={""; IF(1=2, "something", )}
```

[image]